# Angular not parse the template {{value}} in style attribute in IE9 and 10

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I display a list of bars in a NgRepeat and I use the value `frecuency` to display the width of bars in percentage. From what i see IE 9-10 doesn't like this part: `style="width:{{type.frecuency}}%;"`

```
<div class="drp" ng-repeat="type in weeks">
    <div style="width:{{type.frecuency}}%;" class="percentBar">
        <span ng-if="type.frecuency > 14">{{type.frecuency}}%</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is this an issue with Angular on IE or my code is the problem.
Thanks

P.S.
I know that i could make a class but modifying the style attribute is faster.

Solution:  `ng-style="setBarWidth(type.frecuency);"`

```
     scope.setBarWidth = function(width) {
        return {width: width+'%'}; 
     };
```

Comment: Does it work with `ng-style`?

Comment: +1 ivami, try with ng-style

Comment: Thanks guys! i got it work with: `ng-style="setBarWidth(type.frecuency);"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using derived values for various HTML attributes, it's always a good idea to use the provided Angular directives to do it. They make sure that the browser sees the values you want it to see and not the binding syntax (in your case `{{type.frecuency}}`)

Here, the `ngStyle` directive should be used.

```
<div class="drp" ng-repeat="type in weeks">
    <div ng-style="width:{{type.frecuency}}%;" class="percentBar">
        <span ng-if="type.frecuency > 14">{{type.frecuency}}%</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

There are similar directives for many other HTML attributes, see the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive) for the full list.

Comment: actually `ng-style="width:{{type.frecuency}}%;"` it won't work in any browser because angular will generate only `ng-style="width:73.13%;"` without the `style` attr

Comment: According to [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle), you should pass an object to ngStyle, i.e.: `ng-style="{ width: type.frequency }"`. This seems to work well. Of course, you can also define the object in your code elsewhere, e.g. `$scope.styles = { width: type.frequency };`, and in the view just do `ng-style="styles"`.